# Compiling Json.NET on Visual Studio 2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008, json.net

I am trying to compile Json.Net on Visual Studio 2008, targeting .NET 2.0 or .NET 3.5.  With either target, I'm getting similar errors:

Targeting .NET 2.0:

```
Error   1   
The type arguments for method  'Newtonsoft.Json.Utilities.LinqBridge.Enumerable.Select<TSource,TResult>
(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TSource>, 
Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.Func<TSource,TResult>)' 
cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.
C:\Json70r1\Source\Src\Newtonsoft.Json\Converters\XmlNodeConverter.cs   260 35  Newtonsoft.Json.Net20
```

On .NET 3.5 :

```
Error   1   The type arguments for method 
'System.Linq.Enumerable.Select<TSource,TResult>
(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TSource>, 
System.Func<TSource,TResult>)' cannot be 
inferred from the usage. Try specifying 
the type arguments explicitly.  
    C:\Json70r1\Source\Src\Newtonsoft.Json\Converters\XmlNodeConverter.cs   
260 35  Newtonsoft.Json.Net35
```

NOTE:  I'm using the existing project files named: Newtonsoft.Json.Net20.sln and Newtonsoft.Json.Net35.sln, respectively

I want to say I read somwhere that this issue has to do with VS 2008 (Json.NET wasn't relevant there, however).

Is it possible to compile Json.NET in VS 2008, or do I need a newer compiler to generate the .dll targeted at 2.0.

The included .dll for 2.0 works fine for us, but I need to modify some functionality so I need the source.

Comment: Witch version of JSON.net do you have?

Comment: Do you downloaded directly of nuget? If so when? If you downloaded the zip it should be like JsonXYrZ.zip X major version Y minor version and Z a revision so the version would be X.Y.Z inside you should have an folder with the zip name, only without the '.zip'

Comment: Version Json70r1.  I downloaded the .zip from json.net directly.

Comment: Updated the above question to reflect the slight difference in error with .net 3.5 and .net 2.0 (Linq of course exists in .net 3.5)